# Ownership of shares

Tags: stocks

How can I find out whether I own a certain amount of shares? My broker is just sending acknowledgements produced by his own company, but I would like to have the evidence from a third party? DRS may be? How can I get it?

Comment: Can you edit and add country tag.

Comment: Find out the share registry that the company belongs to.

Comment: I voted to close because you need to specify a country or exchange or broker or something.  Right now this question is unclear

Answer (score 0):

Generally each broker uses a custodian bank to actually hold the shares, in my case my broker uses citibank. If you contact the custodian they will be able to tell you what shares are in your name, and transfer the physical certificates if you request.Cant promise that this will be free of charge though.